# Loop through a column and change value of another column based on cell values in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following script should change cell values in column K based on values in column D. However, the comparator is not working, it always returns "NO".

Is range.toString the correct syntax? I think I'm not comparing Apples to Apples.

```
function Test1() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = ss.getSheetByName("report");
   var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
   var range;

  /* Loop through Column D and find cells equal to order payment
  and set Column K value based on it */

   for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      range = s.getRange('D' + i );
      if (range.toString() == "Order Payment") {
        range.offset(0, 6).setValue("YES"); 
      }
     else {
       range.offset(0,6).setValue("NO");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: range = s.getRange('D' + i ).getValue();. Should not need to string

Answer (score 1):

`range.getValue() == "Order Payment"` is the correct syntax instead of `range.toString()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17453902)

Comment: @AngocA How does this not answer the question? The question is "Is range.toString the correct syntax?" and the answer is "range.getValue() == "Order Payment" is the correct syntax instead of range.toString()